# How to enable ec2 tag access via Instance Metadata Service through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, tagging

I would like to have my CloudFormation Launch template enable the EC2 Tag Access. I am seeing it on the Launch Template options in the console.

[image]

Which means I technically could add it to my Launch Template, but I would rather keep all of my configuration changes in source control. So that isn't really an option. I know there is a way to turn it on via [CLI, and Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#work-with-tags-in-IMDS)

I started digging through documentation, but I couldn't find anything. Is there a place I can go to see the progress on CloudFormation capabilities and maybe even implement this myself in AWS's codebase?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I am working on adding a custom resource. I feel pretty confident that will get the job done until it is added to the CloudFormation out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is not directly supported in CloudFormation, you can create your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). So as long as any AWS SDK supports your functionality, you can add it to your CloudFormation templates as well.

For general view of what is supported and not yet supported in CloudFormation, you can got to official AWS github page [cloudformation-coverage-roadmap](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/projects/1). You can also create an [issue there](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues) to report missing or broken functionality.

Comment: I am studying for my AWS Dev Ops Pro certification. I will create this over the next week or so, and will post my solution when I get it working so anyone else can use it.